# Issue with InDesign startup script not loading images from XML import

Tags: javascript, xml, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am trying to do an XML import automatically from a startup script when a document is loaded. I am successful in getting most of the content to populate, but images are being ignored. Everything works, including images, when I do a manual 'Import XML' through the UI, or through a manual script.

Below is my manual script:

```js
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var xmlFile = File('/c/Full/Path/To/data.xml');

myDocument.importXML(xmlFile);
```

But the goal is to do it on startup. Below is my startup script:

```js
#targetengine "session"

app.addEventListener('afterOpen', function(myEvent) {
    if (myEvent.target.constructor.name !== 'Document') {
        return;
    }

    var myDocument = myEvent.target;
    var xmlFile = File('/c/Full/Path/To/data.xml');

    myDocument.importXML(xmlFile);
});
```

Below is the XML tag for the image:

```
<Image href="file:///C:/Full/Path/To/Image/02.png" />
```

I'm wondering if there is an issue with the `'afterOpen'` event callback, and that's the reason why it works manually using the same method, but not in the startup script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the issue by avoiding the event listener altogether.

```js
main();  

function main () {  

    // create a path for a file object  
    var curFile = File('/c/Path/To/file.indd');  
    var xmlFile = File('/c/Path/To/data.xml');  

    // close app if files don't exist  
    if (!curFile.exists || !xmlFile.exists) {  
        app.quit(SaveOptions.NO);  
    }  

    // open the file  
    var curDoc = app.open(curFile);  

    // import the xml  
    curDoc.importXML(xmlFile);  

    // create a new file object  
    var pdfFile = new File(curFile.parent + '/' + curFile.name + '.pdf');  

    // export to pdf  
    curDoc.exportFile(ExportFormat.PDF_TYPE, pdfFile);  

    // close app  
    app.quit(SaveOptions.NO);  

}
```

Comment: Why is the need for closing the app ?

Comment: I don't want to have InDesign taking up resources when it's not needed. I have a PowerShell script that listens for changes to XML files in a specific directory and launches InDesign when it detects a change. Then the startup script opens the necessary document(s), does the import, exports to PDF, then closes the app.

Comment: Ok tanks for the explanation.